# VB.NET What is the best way to get files from directories and sub directories

Tags: vb.net, directory, subdirectory

I've been wondering what is the fastest and most efficient way to get files from directories and subdirectories in vb.net?
ive tried these:

> Method 1

```
Private Sub getallfiles(filelocation As String)

        Try
            For Each item As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(filelocation)
                    Me.Invoke(Sub() ListBox1.Items.Add(item))
                    Me.Invoke(Sub() ListBox1.SelectedIndex = ListBox1.Items.Count - 1)
            Next
            For Each folder As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetDirectories(filelocation)
                Me.Invoke(Sub() getallfiles(folder))
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Sub
```

> Method 2

```
Dim FilesFromDir() As String = Directory.GetFiles("C:\Users\user\Documents\TextNotes", "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
ListBox3.Items.AddRange(FilesFromDir)
```

Comment: Then you should do some research on that. This site is about answering questions on specific problems in code you have written. You haven't encountered any problems yet so it's too soon to ask a question here. If your question sounds like "I don't know X" then that means you need to research X. Questions here should be of the form "I am trying to do X and this is how I tried it but it did Y rather than X".

Comment: What did you try up to now?

Comment: What is wrong with the recursive variant of GetFiles?  (Btw. there is another way to get files: the IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles command En https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd383571%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 )

Comment: that method with the getfiles. will stop if the file is a system file or protected. and stops the process of getting all the files

Comment: You don't need two `Me.Invoke()` calls, that definitely slows things down. You can shorten them to one multiline lambda expression: https://pastebin.com/SQEUETaK -- Also, use `Me.BeginInvoke` instead. It prevents the current thread from being blocked while the code is sent to run on the UI.

Comment: Up to now this sounds like a x-y-problem (http://xyproblem.info/). Please formulate your real problem.

Comment: I think your question as it stands might be better suited for `Code Review`

Comment: This simple thing can get much more complicated than it looks like, if you adventure into the wild. You need to check if the Directory is not a Reparse Point [FileAttributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileattributes(v=vs.110).aspx), then use the [Directory.GetAccessControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0dw80ts%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method to verify whether you have the rights to parse it. In both cases, you'll need to have means to skip it. More tricks await...

Comment: I always use the first because the 2nd won't work if one of the file or folder has access problem. I wouldn't catch all exceptions, just the security ones.

Comment: "I've been wondering what is the fastest and most efficient way" so you thought you'd ask us instead of just timing it for yourself?

Comment: by "I've been wondering what is the fastest and most efficient way" i mean is there a better way of doing that

Answer (score 1):

Instead of hitting the ListBox on each iteration, add the items to a list. Then call the .BeginUpdate and .EndUpdate so the listbox only has to redraw once.

```
Private Sub getallfiles(filelocation As String)
        Dim lstFiles As New List(Of String)
        Try
            For Each item As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(filelocation)
                lstFiles.Add(item)
            Next
            For Each folder As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetDirectories(filelocation)
                getallfiles(folder)
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
        Me.Invoke(Sub()
          ListBox1.BeginUpdate()
          ListBox1.Items.AddRange(lstFiles.ToArray)
          ListBox1.EndUpdate()
      End Sub)
End Sub
```

Comment: For the record you can join the three `Me.Invoke` calls into one (saving you additional execution time) by using a multiline lambda expression, like this: https://pastebin.com/3EDRYisS -- Also, you shouldn't be calling `Me.Invoke` on `getallfiles(folder)`. Doing so will move the loop to the UI thread, freezing the entire UI.

Comment: @VisualVincent Thank you for the corrections. I am not familiar with threading and was just following the OP's pattern.